# Like box returns blank page

Tags: facebook-likebox

Was suppose to add a Facebook like-box.
Used the page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ before to create like boxes. But for this adress http://www.facebook.com/norrkopingdolphins.ungdomskansli  nothing happens. Anyone who has idea why? Name to long?

Comment: Any error in Developer Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Facebook Pages can be Liked. Create a Facebook Page for the person via [Create a Page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create/).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an "s" to the http address in your code.

https://www.facebook.com/norrkopingdolphins.ungdomskansli